# WooCommerce Custom Payment Gateway 2 Step Checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, payment-method

I am using WordPress + WooCommerce with CCAvenue Payment Gateway Plugin.

Now the issue I am facing is that the checkout process is a 3 Step Checkout. First on the Checkout Page I click on PLACE ORDER.

Then a new page appears with the Order Number, Date, Total and Payment Method.

Then I again need to click on place order before I am redirected the payment gateway page. From the script I found that its passing the second page details via these specific lines of code in the script

```
add_action('woocommerce_receipt_ccavenue', array( $this, 'receipt_page'));

function receipt_page( $order ) {
    echo '<p>'.__('Please confirm your order on clicking the PLACE ORDER Button Below. To get redirected to the CCAvenue Payment Gateway', 'ccavenue').'</p>';
    echo $this->generate_ccavenue_form( $order);
}
```

I contacted their support but they say it is a part of Woocommerce due to which this page is generated. But I find that Paypal or some other gateway do not need 3 steps but only 2 steps that is once I click on Place Order the first time it directly goes to the payment gateway without the need for an additional step.

Is there something that can be done to convert it into a 2 step process?

Comment: Did you contact the plugin authors? Either the customer enters the credit card info on the checkout page and goes to the thank you page. Or the customer is redirected to the processor's (ex: PayPal) and then back to the Thank you page. If they won't do that, I'd advise switching payment processors.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Yes I did contact them. They say its part of woocommerce due to which the additional page comes up. But as mentioned above within their script I see the receipt_page function which does all this. They say this cannot be avoided but I feel it can be. Once I press Place Order it should redirect me to the Payment Gateway page. But here an additional page is generated which I think affects usability / customer experience.